# Android programming: Adding TextView above pane

Tags: android

Up until 12 hours ago I had never touched Android programming or even XML. As such my question may appear incredibly stupid.

Basically my "app" (if you can call it that) consists of a tabbed fragments with placed immediately below the "app_name" of my app.

What I would like to do is to add some STATIC text immediately below the app_name and (at the same time) immediately above the tabbed fragments -- we are talking about a SINGLE text "element" just be clear. What I have tried so far has been.... unsuccesful. Basically, I thought it would be as follows:

My main.xml currently looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
          android:layout_below="@+id/AnalogClock01"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

where I believe the TextView component would be all the XML required to add the static text-field I want. Subsequently I add:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
tv1.setText("Additional information");
```

to my MainActivity.java file immediately after calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) and my naivity begs me to belive that it should work, but clearly it doesnt (in fact the app crashes when loading it into the emulator).

As this does not work the purpose of my post is to hopefully get one or more of you to offer a solution to "fix" this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Subsequently I add: ... MainActivity.java file immediately after calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

If you're doing that, you're going to have a problem.

You need add

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
tv1.setText("Additional information");
```

**after** `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

First you need to give your `Activity` something to display (a UI) *then* you can modify the components that make up that UI.

Otherwise `findViewById()` will return null and you will end up with `NullPointerException`s

Some other things to note:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/AnalogClock01"
```

1. You don't have a AnalogClock01 defined in that layout. If it is defined somewhere else though, you *might* not crash your app, but things probably won't work as expected.
2. Even if you did have AnalogClock01 in that layout, you do not access it with `@+id/` since you're not assigning an id, but accessing it. Use `@id/` instead.

And

```
android:text="@+id/TextView01"
```

is also an issue.

To reference Strings from your `res/values/strings.xml` file, use `@string/string_name` No `+` either, and definitely not an `id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions and comments. I will give it a go tomorrow and hope it works. (will mark the best answer after some trial and error tomorrow).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make the activity have multiple layouts in the one activity.

This may help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#Position

Also try the .onStart() method instead, although I don't exactly know if it will change anything.